# Diagnosing / Troubleshooting SMB mount

Tags: cifs

Ubuntu 22.04: A Synology NAS SMB mount tested good with a Mac.   A list of Samba share returned by MacOS Finder:

[image]

I would like to mount the SMB share:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.8.109/home -o username=****,password=****** /home/user/NAS_mount
```

however, an error is returned:

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
```

What is the starting point / questions / diagnostic to understand / resolve the error?

Answer (score 5):

Success!

I Googled the error:   "mount error(13) -Windows" to avoid Windows.
https://serverfault.com/a/636785 indicted that passwords with punctuation characters should be in a file

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.X.XXX/home -o credentials=/home/user/credential.txt /home/user/NAS_mount
```

Comment: If the mounted filesystem is under your control, I would suggest removing the punctuation from the password (and making it longer if you're concerned). This will probably bite you again.